# how to package my git repo and publish to my launchpad ppa

Tags: package-management, ppa, repository, git

I have GitHub repo named *logger*. Its a C++ library. What I am doing to package and publish to my launchpad ppa is

```
cd
rm -Rf Packages2
mkdir Packages2
cp -R workspace/logger/ Packages2/logger-1.0
cd Packages2/logger-1.0
rm -R build/
rm -R debian/
rm -R dist/
rm -R nbproject/
rm -R QtBuild/
rm -Rf .git
rm Makefile.old 
rm CMakeLists.txt.user

cd ~/Packages2/logger-1.0/
make clean
cd ..
rm -Rf logger-1.0.tar.gz logger_* logger logger-dev_* liblogger1_* logger1_* build-area/logger-1.0 build-area/logger_* build-area liblogger1_* build-area/logger-dev_* build-area/logger1*

tar -czf logger-1.0.tar.gz logger-1.0
bzr dh-make logger 1.0 logger-1.0.tar.gz
ly
cd logger/debian/
rm *ex *EX
cp ~/workspace/logger/debian/control ./
cp ~/workspace/logger/debian/changelog ./
cp ~/workspace/logger/debian/copyright ./
cp ~/workspace/logger/debian/rules ./
cp ~/workspace/logger/debian/README.Debian ./
cp ~/workspace/logger/debian/README.source ./
bzr commit -m "Initial commit of Debian packaging."
bzr builddeb -- -us -uc # -sd
bzr builddeb -S -- # -sd
bzr tag release-1.1
cd ../../build-area
pbuilder-dist xenial build logger_1.0-0ubuntu1.dsc
cd ../logger
bzr push lp:~satyagowtham-k-gmail/+junk/logger-package
cd ../build-area
dput ppa:satyagowtham-k-gmail/ferryfair.ppa logger_1.0-0ubuntu1_source.changes
```

Now I came to know that we can use `git` instead of `bzr`. I found very sparse documentation regarding packaging and publishing to launchpad ppa.
How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out to be very simple

```bsh
cd ~/workspace/logger
git tag v1.0
git checkout -b ubuntu/xenial
mkdir debian
cd debian
vi changelog
vi control
vi rules
vi liblogger-dev.dirs
vi liblogger-dev.install
vi liblogger1.dirs
vi liblogger1.install
mkdir source
vi source/format
vi compat
cd ..
git add debian
git commit -a -m "packed from git"
# Check if full build works (so we don't upload a broken source package)
gbp buildpackage --git-upstream-tag='v1.0' --git-debian-branch=ubuntu/xenial
# Build source package
debuild -S -sa
# Upload source package to ppa
dput ppa:satyagowtham-k-gmail/ferryfair.ppa ../logger_1.0-0ubuntu1_source.changes
```

that is all.

Comment: @user.dz thanks for suggestion on `.install` files

Comment: So was the only issue, does it build correctly now? BTW, `.install` file are required if you are building multiple binaries from same source package. Single binary, every thing is going to same basket :), right!

Comment: @user.dz yes build successful. I didn't understand your comment on .install file differing with single and multiple binaries. I will introspect it when I am building a multiple binaries package

Comment: Well you have a source package `logger` that generate 2 binaries packages `liblogger-dev` & `liblogger1`.  How the deb builder (`gbp buildpackage`,`pbuilder`,`debuild`...) knows where to put each file in `liblogger-dev` OR `liblogger1` ? It is using `*.install` & `.dirs` files (which work like  a manifest)

Comment: @user.dz Yeah! everything goes into same basket!. Now I am packaging a single binary file. I had to name project logger as liblogger1 since its a library. Now how to name my single executable project ferryfair?

Comment: Seems to me, you haven't  got the idea I want to tell you, Ok.... `liblogger-dev` is also a binary package, so you are making 2 (i'm talking using `DEBIAN PACKAGER` idioms ).  The "debian source package"="upstream source archive(origin)"+"debian control files (debian folder)" . The "debian binary package `.deb`" is any package which was generated from the build (even is  empty or contains just headers).

Comment: :( am I too bad in explaining ? please did you get my idea? :D may be I should go in a different way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49309/discussion-between-necktwi-and-user-dz).